# UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight smoothen animation

Tags: ios

I am trying to give the flip effect to a UIview as if on one side I had some content and on the other side I had some other in the following way:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:FlipView duration:0.7
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                           //imageView.image = secondImage;
                           FlipImage.hidden = YES;
                           for (UIButton *btn in arrayoflabels) {
                               btn.hidden = YES;
                           }

                           containerViewSplashit.hidden = NO;
                           containerViewSplashit.alpha = 1.0;

                           closeButton.hidden = NO;
                       } completion:nil];
```

The only problem is that it flips and then when it finishes flipping, it shows the hidden content I want to show, but it doesn't give that front to back effect that it swops side when it passes the middle. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to ad the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option to the animation option because you have animatable changes in your block (hidden, alpha).

Comment: Great answer, works just fine, I did: (UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent) ....+1 :)